# SSIS variable not getting set when assigning it from C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a SSIS package have some variables defined in it (say for example, TempTableName). I am creating a temp table in my C# code (windows service) and assigning the name of that temp table to a package variable. On calling the SSIS package, the package fails with the error message saying  the temp table name is invalid, actually it is blank. What I don't understand is why the variable is not getting set from C#?

My C# code

```
oPkg = oApp.LoadPackage(mySSISPackagePath, null);
Variables vars= null;
if (oPkg.Variables.Contains("User::TempTableName"))
{
   oPkg.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::TempTableName", ref vars);
   vars["User::TempTableName"].Value = "MyTempTableName";
}
```

Comment: Try this: `Dts.Variables["TempTableName"].Value = "MyTempTableName"`. And if it doesn't work, maybe MessageBox some values just for debugging!

Comment: @makciook: That also did not work.